# Tensor of type $(1,1)$

Tags: differential-geometry

I am a bit stuck here with this problem: If $A$ is a tensor of type $(1,1)$ and has the same component with respect to every basis, show that $A$ is a multiple of $\langle\,\,,\,\,\rangle$.

I tried with a fixed basis $e_{i}$ and its dual $\epsilon^{j}$, and let $A=A^{e,i}_{j}e^{i}\otimes \epsilon^{j}$. Suppose I have another basis $f_{i}$ and its dual $\varphi^{j}$, so I have

$f_{j}=b^{n}_{j}e_{n}$ and $\varphi^{i}=a_{m}^{i}\epsilon^{m}$, with $A=A^{f,i}_{j}f_{i}\otimes\varphi^{j}$

Plugging into the expression I will have

$A^{f,i}_{j}=a^{i}_{m}b^{n}_{j}A^{e,m}_{n}=a^{i}_{m}b^{n}_{j}A^{f,m}_{n}$

where the last equality uses the assumption. I am still unable to conclude that $A$ is a multiple of inner product...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't see how $\langle\,\,,\,\,\rangle$ is of type $(1,1)$, and anyway this tensor certainly doesn't have the same components in all basee.

Comment: If a tensor has the same component with respect to every basis, then the tensor has to be a scalar. That's what the notion of "scalar" in language of tensor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct statement here is that $A$ should be a scalar multiple of the *identity map*. Recall that tensors of type $(1,1)$ represent linear maps from a vector space to itself. The matrix version here is the statement:

> If $P^{-1}AP = A$ for all invertible $P$, then $A = cI$.

Equivalently, if $PA=AP$ for all invertible $P$, then $A=cI$. What you didn't use in your argument above is that your matrices $a$ and $b$ are inverses of one another.